# Elasticsearch : How to list each analyzer used by a specific index

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, analyzer, snowball

I need to find out which analyzer (type, language..) is configured in a specific index.
I tried `http://localhost:9200/wazzup/_mapping` but it only gives information about field names/types.

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The analyzer are part of the index settings, you can retrieve them using the [get index settings api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/wazzup/_settings'
```

Also, if you want to see how they behave, have a look at the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

Comment: The _settings query is not returning the analysed/not_analyzed setting of each field type

Comment: Right, if no specific analyzer has been set on the index. If a specific analyzer are set, _settings query return all details about analyzer.